# Three.js "Raycasting Points" example – why are there different types of point cloud?

Tags: three.js

In the example [Interactive Raycasting Points](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_raycasting_points) there are 4 different functions to generate the point cloud:

```
1. generatePointcloud (with buffer geometry)
2. generateIndexedPointcloud (buffer geometry with indices)
3. generateIndexedWithOffsetPointcloud (buffer geometry with added drawcall)
4. generateRegularPointcloud (with normal geometry)
```

Could someone explain what the difference is between these 4 types, and if there are any performance benefits/certain situations where one is suited more than the others?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the example [Interactive Raycasting Points](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_raycasting_points) is to demonstrate that raycasting against `THREE.Points` works for a variety of geometry types.

So-called "regular geometry", `THREE.Geometry`, is the least memory-efficient geometry type, and in general, has longer load times than `THREE.BufferGeometry`.

`BufferGeometry` can be "indexed" or "non-indexed". Indexed `BufferGeometry`, when used with meshes, allows for vertices to be reused; that is, faces that share an edge can share a vertex. In the case of point clouds, however, I do not see a benefit to the "indexed" type.

`BufferGeometry` with draw calls -- now called groups -- allows for only a subset of the geometry to be rendered, and also allows for a different material index to be associated with each group.

---

The function `generateIndexedWithOffsetPointcloud` appears to have been named when draw calls, a.k.a. groups, were called "offsets".

I do not believe raycasting in three.js honors groups. I believe it raycasts against the entire geometry. In fact, I am not sure groups are working correctly at all in the example you reference.

three.js r.73